# Raspberry Pi 4 unable to run aarch64 binary with aarch64 kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, software-compatibility

I followed this instruction to enable 64 bit kernel.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=250730

And I am pretty sure now my kernel is 64 bit.

```bsh
$ uname -a
Linux RPi4 5.4.51-v8+ #1327 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jul 23 11:11:34 BST 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

But I can't run any 64bit binaries on it.

```bsh
$ chmod 755 *
$ file ./busybox
./busybox: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/bin/linker64, stripped
$ ./busybox
Failed to execute process './busybox'. Reason:
The file './busybox' does not exist or could not be executed.
$ ld ./busybox
./busybox: file not recognized: file format not recognized
$ ldd ./busybox
        not a dynamic executable
```

binary source: [busybox](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-9/development/useful-64-bit-aarch64-binaries-busybox-t2931373)

---

Is there any way to run arbitrary aarch64 binaries on my PRi4?

---

I tried install docker on my RPi4, too. But the docker engine also be 32 bit, and I can only pull armhf images...

---

2020/07/29 Another try:

force docker to pull arm64 version of Ubuntu image

```
$ docker manifest inspect ubuntu
{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json",
   "manifests": [
##########<ignore useless output>##########
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 1152,
         "digest": "sha256:8351cb483b295a97ee3cc15150285a58ccf0669e422d4730a9a608988bd5e902",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "arm64",
            "os": "linux",
            "variant": "v8"
         }
      },
##########<ignore useless output>##########
   ]
}
$ docker pull ubuntu@sha256:8351cb483b295a97ee3cc15150285a58ccf0669e422d4730a9a608988bd5e902
$ docker tag acd9dae93dea ubuntu
```

Run the image

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu bash
#Nothing happen, no error message, no tty spawn. 

docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                            PORTS               NAMES
b098badc2c00        ubuntu              "bash"                   8 seconds ago        Exited (159) 6 seconds ago                            hopeful_bhabha
```

The only thing I known is it exit with code 159.

Anyone knows the reason? The docker image is for aarch64, all binary should be aarch64, and my kernel is aarch64.

Why I can't run it?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I use 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04 on my RPi 3B+, and it seems to run any 64- or 32-bit program without any issues, including 64-bit Docker.

Comment: You are missing the dynamic linker used, "interpreter /system/bin/linker64", the path and linker do look a bit strange, where is the busybox binary from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
/busybox: ELF 64-bit [...] dynamically linked
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is totally normal -- I suspect you have some idea of what this refers to, since you tried `ldd` on it -- but of course what it was linked to when compiled were 64-bit userland libraries that you do not have.

There are two things you can try:

1. Install those libraries too.  Finding out what are they may take some work as obviously `ldd` on the Pi isn't saying, but I'd guess the list for `busybox` is not too hefty (`ldd` on a stock version somewhere should give some clues).  Remember, you have to check those `.so` files for their own dependencies and include those.
2. Compile a statically linked `busybox`.  This requires you have an aarch64 system or cross-compiler to do it with.  I'd guess this commonly enough done when `busybox` is used on embedded systems as the entire userland.<sup>1</sup>

In case you don't understand the static vs. dynamic linking issue, [this is a pretty succinct explanation](https://cs-fundamentals.com/tech-interview/c/difference-between-static-and-dynamic-linking#:%7E:text=Static%20linking%20is%20the%20process,into%20the%20final%20executable%20image.&text=Dynamic%20linking%20is%20performed%20at,built%20into%20the%20executable%20files).  I would try installing an aarch64 OS on a card temporarily, something Debian derived/related such as Ubuntu, and see if #1 will work, then #2.

I also thought of trying to add an aarch64 repo to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
      deb [arch=arm64]  http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib
```

But I tried this quickly and in the end I don't think apt will cooperate.  This would also cause a problem if you have the normal busybox installed.

---

1. In fact, I notice there's a `busybox-static` package, and I did try downloading the aarch64 one to a Raspbian Pi: http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/busybox/busybox-static_1.30.1-4_arm64.deb but this also fails with `Exec format error`, which leads me to believe this is simply not possible.

Comment: Thank your explanation. Because I want to run arbitrary aarch64 binaries on my PRi4.. Is there any to install all those libraries?

Comment: That's another question ;) but I would not bother asking:  I think you are out of luck, I made some changes above, start with the footnote.

Comment: I tried to chroot a 64bit os tree, succeed. The problem is my OS lack of 64 bit dynamic libraries.